# Print PDF on Canon LBP2900 through CUPS functioning on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, linux, printing, raspberry-pi, cups

I am using CUPS server to print PDF files. Every HP printer is working great, but, Canon LBP2900 is giving problems. I have followed [this blog](https://brain.cdauth.eu/2014/01/16/canon-lbp2900-printer-on-linux/) which is based on [this github repository](https://github.com/agalakhov/captdriver). From CUPS web interface and command line (using lpr command), I can successfully print the CUPS test page, but, cannot print PDFs generated by [Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/) (a python lib used to generate PDFs). Can any one please suggest a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you show use the commands you use? Also, did you look at the logs?
Did you tried with other PDF file ?

Comment: sudo lpr -P <printer_name> <file_name>. This is the command I use. This command works great with the CUPS test file

Comment: I get the following errors in the log on trying to print any other PDF,
1. CAPT: unable to communicate with printer
2. Request for non-absolute resource ""
3.  Unable to send data to printer.

Comment: Seems a common problem, read this Answer, maybe you can adapt it to r-pi-3: https://askubuntu.com/questions/326620/printing-problem-canon-lbp2900

Comment: I got it working by making changes in the PPD file. Thank you anyway :

Comment: @GaurangDeshpande Which changes? I struggle with the same problem